# Unable to pass image downloaded from the firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, swift5

I cannot have the image shown on the detailViewController which I retrieve from the firebase database.

I've tried to solve it by looking at other examples such as the one below but I couldn't get it working.
[(iOS + Firebase) Unable to pass the Image to the next ViewController from a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628059/ios-firebase-unable-to-pass-the-image-to-the-next-viewcontroller-from-a-uita)

This is my image service:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import IHProgressHUD

class ImageService {

     static let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

    static func downloadImage(withURL url:URL, completion: @escaping (_ image:UIImage?, _ url:URL)->()) {
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, responseURL, error in
            var downloadedImage:UIImage?


            if let data = data {
                downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
            }

            if downloadedImage != nil {
                self.cache.setObject(downloadedImage!, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(downloadedImage, url)
                IHProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }

        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }

    static func getImage(withURL url:URL, completion: @escaping (_ image:UIImage?, _ url:URL)->()) {
        if let image = cache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString) {
            completion(image, url)
        } else {
            downloadImage(withURL: url, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I construct my collectionViewCell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if collectionView === self.vegatableCollectionView {

            let productCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "vegatable", for: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell
            productCell.set(cell: veggies[indexPath.row])


            if let productImageURL = cell?.productImageURL {
                cell?.productImageURL = productImageURL
            }

            return productCell
}
```

This is what happens when I select a cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView == self.vegatableCollectionView {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVegetableDetail", sender: veggies[indexPath.item])
}
}
```

This is how I segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showVegetableDetail" {

            let destination = segue.destination as! VegetableDetailViewController
            destination.selectedProduct = sender as! Product
            }
}
```

And finally this is my detailViewController:

```
    var veggies = [Product]()
    var veggieRef: DatabaseReference?
    var selectedProduct: Product?
    weak var cell:Product?

    @IBOutlet weak var headerTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemDescription: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self

        getTheData()

    }

    func getTheData() {

        headerTitle.text = selectedProduct?.productName
        itemDescription.text = selectedProduct?.productDescription
}
}
```

I simply want to get the image from the database and show it in the detailViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the way that you are approaching this problem.

I would say the reason it is not working is caused by how you are downloading the image. When downloading images and setting them I have found that the easiest way to do it is using the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) library, why reinvent the wheel?

This has specialised functions which will do what you are currently trying to do manually.

The function I would focus on is:

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.imageURL.com/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

This function will set the image from a URL. It covers downloading the image and then setting it, whilst also allowing you to pass through a placeholder image to be shown while your image is loaded.

In this case your code would be simplified to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView === self.vegatableCollectionView {

        let productCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "vegatable", for: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell
        productCell.set(cell: veggies[indexPath.row])
        productCell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: cell?.productImageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "loading_vege.png"))

        return productCell
    }
}
```

This simplifies everything by only requiring you to download the information from firebase including the image url. This can then be passed into the cell and loaded.

**Bonus:** 
SDWebImage also caches the image data for you. This means if you load and come back your images will be cached for a certain amount of time.

Comment: This honestly saved my life @simon_smiley. I was struggling with this for the last 10 days. I actually came across with SDWebImage but couldn't figure it out how to do it. But the part I was missing was actually there. Your suggestion is way much easier than using the way I download and fetch data. I appreciate your time.